# Make WordPress use timezone for email Date header

Tags: email, date, date-time, timezones

My WordPress installations send emails with the Date header specified in UTC:

```
Date: Wed, 18 Jul 2018 15:18:50 +0000
```

I would prefer that the mail be sent with dates encoded in localtime, which is properly configured on the server, and in the Wordpress general settings to `America/New_York`.

I tried using the [WP Mail SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/) plugin and configuring it to send mail through our SMTP server, but it did nothing to change the Date header.

How can I configure WordPress to send mail using the offset corresponding to my timezone?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need the same thing.

Comment: I don't believe I did, and I no longer work with wordpress, sorry.